# Term for a product of groups that is neither direct, nor semi-direct, but generalises semi-direct ones

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, terminology

Suppose $H$ and $K$ are subgroups of a group $G$ such that every element $g\in G$ can be uniquely written as $g = hk$ with $h\in H$ and $k\in K$.  (It follows then that every element $g\in G$ can also be uniquely written as $g = kh$ with $h\in H$ and $k\in K$.)

What is the standard term for this kind of a product of $H$ and $K$?  (It is not always a direct or a semi-direct product.)

A useful example is the decomposition of $SL(2,\mathbf{R})$ into a product of $SO(2,\mathbf{R})$ and the subgroup of upper-triangular matrices with positive diagonal elements from $SL(2,\mathbf{R})$.

Comment: It is the product $G=HK=KH$, with the uniqueness condition. This has no single name, I think. The Iwasawa decomposition yields $SL_2(\Bbb R)=KAN$ with $g=kan$ unique representation, yes.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zappa%E2%80%93Sz%C3%A9p_product

Answer (score 3):

No doubt the literature varies, but often the term *factorization* is used the situation in which $G = HK$ for proper subgroups $H, K \le G$. For the stronger situation you describe in which moreover $H \cap K = \{1\}$, the term *exact factorization* gets used. See for example  the following paper.

*Liebeck, Martin W.; Praeger, Cheryl E.; Saxl, Jan*, [**On factorizations of almost simple groups**](https://doi.org/10.1006/jabr.1996.0333), J. Algebra 185, No. 2, 409-419 (1996). [ZBL0862.20016](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0862.20016).